# What is the differece between my codes when find checkbox in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, internet-explorer-8

I have tree type of checkbox which class is named `checkAll,checkRow,checkCell` in my grid. When I click `checkAll` checkbox ,all the checkbox will be checked.When I click the `checkRow` checkbox,the checkbox in this row will be checked.  Now I use the same code to create  `checkAll,checkRow` event, I find 
`checkAll` event works well, but in `checkRow` event it is wrong. It says Jscript error. And I try to change it use the jQuery way and it works well. What is the differece between my codes when finding the checkbox in IE8?

**First way: checkAll works well, checkRow do not work**

```
$("#checkAll").on("click", function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target), item, checked = target.prop("checked"),
    checkboxes = $("#Grid input");
    checkboxes.each(function (i, v) {
        item = $(v);
        if(!item.prop("disabled"))
            item.prop("checked", checked);
    });
});

$("#Grid").on("click", ".checkRow", function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target), checked = target.prop("checked"),
    td = target.parent("td"), tr = td.parent("tr"),
    checkboxes = tr.find("input[class!='checkRow']");
    checkboxes.each(function (i, v) {
        item = $(v); //in this row Jscript error,wrong property in IE8,but firfox work well
        item.prop("checked", checked);
    });
});
```

**Second way in checkrow event and work well**

```
$("#Grid").on("click", ".checkRow", function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target), checked = target.prop("checked"),
    td = target.parent("td"), tr = td.parent("tr"),
    checkboxes = tr.find("input[class!='checkRow']");
    checkboxes.prop("checked", checked);//work well
});
```

Comment: I think you need to work out where the failures occur; use `console.log()` and look at the values of the variables. IE 8 isn't supported in the jQuery 2.x, branch so you may need to use [jQuery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/).

Comment: I have work out,the failures . 'item = $(v); //in this row Jscript error,wrong property in IE8'

Comment: Use change event, not click

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: JScript error:Object does not support this operation

Comment: @A.Wolff,Why do you suggest me ' 
Use change event, not click'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `checkRow` event in first way,your variable called item do not declare.So firefox works well but IE8 can not work.